# neo4j community detection with 2 nodes types

Tags: neo4j, cluster-analysis

I'm new to neo4j. I've been looking at community detection from the :play data_science example using Game of Thrones characters relationships.

In this example, there is only one node type (Character) and the community detection is ran using label propagation

```
CALL algo.labelPropagation(
  'MATCH (c:Character) RETURN id(c) as id',
  'MATCH (c:Character)-[rel]->(c2) RETURN id(c) as source, id(c2) as target, SUM(rel.weight) as weight',
  'OUTGOING',
  {graph:'cypher', partitionProperty: 'community'})
```

Would it be possible to do a community detection on a graph having 2 types of nodes (say, Character and Location, where we want a community of characters and where characters are linked indirectly through the locations they have visited)?

I tried the following queries:

```
CALL algo.labelPropagation(
  'MATCH (c:Character) RETURN id(c) as id',
  'MATCH (c:Character)-[*1..2]->(p:Character) RETURN id(c) as source, id(p) as target',
  'OUTGOING',
  {graph:'cypher', partitionProperty: 'community'})
```

It does create communities of Characters but not as I'd have expected based on looking at the graph using

```
match (c:Character)-[r]->(l:Location) return *
```

Is that the correct approach to follow?

Thanks